# cocos2d: SQLite or Core Data? - need to redesign with database because my current App is very slow or crashes sometimes without WiFi

Tags: sqlite, core-data

I decided to develop the internal database instead of parsing JSON data from remote server. I did some searches and need to know which one would be better for my QUIZ APP, SQLite or Core Data? I am not very experienced in database programming, so if some links to learn them are provided, that would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer the question in general. Both are good, it depends on what you're doing. Broadly speaking:

- Core Data is designed around the idea of creating, reading, writing, and searching for your model objects directly. Although it usually uses SQLite internally, that's an implementation detail-- it is *not* simply a SQLite wrapper. You can learn about it at Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), especially the "Technology Overview" and "Basics" sections.
- SQLite is, well, SQL. You get a relational database in a file and you can create, select, and update records in the usual SQL style. SQLite has its own native API which you can read about at the [SQLite home page](http://www.sqlite.org). There are a couple of Objective-C style wrappers that are often easier to use in iOS and Mac apps-- [PLDatabase](http://code.google.com/p/pldatabase/) and [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Which one is best depends on how you need to access your data. Neither is right in every case.

Comment: I might have 6-8 categories of quiz question types and each of them have some data. You can view my older json structure here http://jeewanaryal.web44.net/json/myValidjson.json and I am thinking to design the internal database of the same. If you can suggest me which approach would be efficient, it would be a great help Tom. 
Thanks

Comment: The data structure alone doesn't provide enough information-- either would work. You need to think about how you plan to use the data in the app, learn a little about how both work, and decide based on that.

Comment: My App is in the App Store now. I did not use Coredata or SQLite, I just use JSON as a data storage. Thanks all...